# Where do I ask non-mainstream physics questions?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

Where do I ask non-mainstream physics questions? For instance, a question that links the human mind, physics, neuroscience & perhaps mathematics like-

[According to physics, do our visual thoughts (possibly others) appear to be not real because they occupy physically inaccessible higher dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/510269/according-to-physics-do-our-visual-thoughts-possibly-others-appear-to-be-not)

It wasn't well received in physics stack exchange or psychology & neuroscience stack exchange.

Comment: That is a lot of text in that question, I mean, a heck of a lot. Are you 100% sure all of it is needed to provide enough context for the core of the question to be understood? You run the risk of it being too broad to be answerable.

Comment: You may wish to use area51 to propose a stack called pseudosciences.SE.

Comment: I would have thought that the artifacts arising from the operation of 10^11 adaptive-threshold logic gates, wired into a massively-parallel computer, running an unknown OS, would belong on Computer Science?

Comment: @MartinJames Possibly [ai.se], or [cstheory.se]. Unknown OS indeed.

Answer (score 32):

I don't think that question can be asked anywhere on the Stack Exchange network. These sites are only for *specific, focused questions*. As far as I can tell, what you posted seems to be an essay exploring your ideas on what is real or not. This may well be interesting, but it isn't a question that can be answered. After all, you even highlight it yourself at the end:

> Finally, I just explored my thoughts in the above.I don't claim anything above to be true & I can be wrong or right. Please share your thoughts.

As you said, you're exploring your thoughts and are asking for others to share their thoughts. That is not what these sites are for. We don't do discussion, we don't accept open ended questions. These sites are strictly Q&A, so if you ask a question, it must be of a form that can take a more or less straightforward, specific answer.

It looks like you need a place that is more geared towards hosting discussions instead.

Comment: It wish you were right. Have you ever read the questions and answers on the physics site? (I am not saying we need *more* of this, but IMHO the quality standards are not too high._

Comment: Actually they have been largely fine if you ask me, @Schrödinger'scat.

Comment: @Marc.2377 You will now get mad at me, but I just glanced through your posts on the physics site. Already the first answer I saw is incomplete, at the very least, and you should have paid more attention to [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/383800/is-there-a-proposed-minimum-amount-of-energy#comment860956_383804).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat not mad at all.To be honest I don't figure how that comment is important (you can help me by clarifying). Anyway, what I meant to point out in my previous question is that I find that most questions posted to Physics.SE to be of acceptable quality in that they are formulated in such a way as to query for actual answers, not discussion of 'opinions'. I mean, those who are not are quickly cleaned up by the community. Btw: I'm sure you must be aiming for a higher standard of physics Q&A in that site than me (and others) would expect. _(to be continued...)_

Comment: _(cont)_ and in my opinion, while there is nothing wrong with that, there should be a site similar to MathOverflow, only for high-level physics (I'm aware of Physics Overflow, unfortunately - or not? - it's just not part of the SE network).

Comment: @Marc.2377 The comment essentially say that you can *not* have arbitrarily small units of energy. This was instrumental to cure the UV problem of black body radiation, and lead to the birth of quantum mechanics. My interpretation of the comment is that even if one takes the volume as large as the universe, there is still a minimal excitation energy below we cannot go. (I was participating for a short while on the physics site but quit because of similar concerns.)

Comment: I see! Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

As the [on hold] notice shows, it's about mainstream physics - things that scientists tend to agree about, and which we have a pretty good idea of.

And the science of our day just hasn't yet progressed to an understanding of the human mind to depth you seem to have been asking.

While I personally haven't ever posted there, perhaps [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *might* be able to host this question. No promises.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been deleted, so the only available information is what's posted here.  Just going by that, it sounds like part of what cognitive psychology deals with.  It draws on some other disciplines, but physics wouldn't be one of them.  It's about how cognitive processes work, which is understandable through "brain science".  There's extensive research into this stuff.  To understand it, you would want to get the related science under your belt.  Undergraduate coursework in cognitive psychology might touch on it generally, but that would be a good jumping off point.

It's too complex of a subject to answer well within the intended scope of a Q&A site, and it could well be that there isn't a big concentration of subject matter experts here.  For the heck of it, I entered "cognitive psychology web site" in Google, and it looks like there are a number of sites dedicated to the subject.  That might be a good way to start exploring this.

Comment: From what’s left here, I take it that OP isn’t just interested in cognitive processes or abstract mental images; he’s asking if those mental images reflect actual, concrete, physical dimensions. He wants it to be a matter of physics, not psychology. Answering only from a cognitive POV does not address the heart of his question. In short, he asking about speculative physics, and there’s nowhere to ask such things on the network, as terdon’s answer lays out.

Comment: @DanBron, my impression was that the OP was contemplating explanations for what people experience as thoughts, and speculating as to sources that aren't anchored in the physical sciences as we know them. Yeah, there's no good place to explore the pseudoscience, but pseudoscience isn't needed to understand what, how, and why people have those cognitive experiences.  Learning how the brain works provides the answer to the underlying question (it isn't "X", it's "Y").  Figured it couldn't hurt to provide some direction; but agreed, this network isn't a good venue for exploring the subject matter.